# Looking for a font similar to the one used in the better place logo

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation, sans-serif

I'm trying to track down a free font similar to the one used in the 'better place' logo.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Title](http://www.dafont.com/ubuntu-title.font) - Not an exact match but a close alternative that meets your criteria:

[image]